# Function returning info to console log, but doesn't actually do what it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slideshow

I have a question regarding a image slider script I'm using called **Slippry**. I currently have it integrated into a site I’m working on and I've run into an issue. I’m using the following code to stop the slider when one of the images within the slider is clicked:

**Javascript Code:**

```
// Stop the slider and log click
$('.stop').click(function () {
    slider.stopAuto();
    console.log('stopped');
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<a class=“stop” href=“#123”>
    <img src=“/img/slide.jpg”/>
</a>
```

If I let the slider play through to the slide and click the slide, it will add `stopped` to the JS console, but it won’t stop the slider. If I click the pagination, then click the slide, it adds `stopped` to the JS console and stops the slider.

Why is the function attached to .stop only working when I click the pagination first? Any thoughts?

Comment: Most likely the DOM changed (the element was removed) or you aren't clicking `.stop`

Comment: Why would it be adding `stopped` to the console then?

Comment: Are you saying that the `console.log` line still works, but the `slider.stopAuto` stops working after the first click?

Comment: If you look at the site link in the post above, you'll see the first slide only runs `slider.stopAuto` successfully when I click on one of the sliders pagination buttons first, then the slide itself. If I let it run through without using the pagination buttons, and click a slide, it fails to run `slider.stopAuto`. Both methods adds `stopped` to the console log.

Comment: Your definition of fail may be unconventional. Usually it implies exception, but that prevent log line to run. Please debug your code and clarify what do you mean  "fails".

Comment: Only first slide image is wrapped with a tag, class 'stop'. It pops a div, and slide starts again when closed with button 'X', triggering your start function. What's the problem?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't really know what you're talking about. In the context above, "fail" refers to `slider.stopAuto` not working although `stopped` is added to the console log.

Comment: @J.Cheong Did you actually see the slider stop when the div popped up? I've tested it extensively, and it only pauses when I first click that first pagination button THEN the slide. If I click the slide first without touching pagination, the slider DOES NOT stop.

Comment: You claim that `slider.stopAuto();` doesn't actually execute. This is quite different from doing nothing. Also consider editing your post to provide [MCVE] for future visitors. If you expect personalized help that can't benefit other visitors - consider simply paying someone to fix it for you.

Comment: @MattBeckman Oh, I didn't know slide moves behind the pop. It seems like slippry doesn't stops when it's not paused. I found a post about this. https://github.com/booncon/slippry/issues/93

Comment: @J.Cheong I appreciate you digging into this for me. That link you posted was extremely helpful. I had found another post by the same user that posted that issue, but hadn't found the link you sent yet. It appears there are some timing issues with `slider.stopAuto` and the transitions of the slides. I was able to execute the function `onclick` and then used `setTimeout` to run the script every `50ms` for a full second. This results in the function being called 21 times, and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @J.Cheong I found a solution to this problem.

There is a timing issue with the `slider.stopAuto` function, and the function that transitions the slides. It appears both functions were being called at the same time or close enough that they were conflicting with one another. I added the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    slider.stopAuto();
    console.log('50ms - Paused');
}, 50);
```

I repeated calling the script every `50ms` for an entire second, thus resulting in 21 calls for `slider.stopAuto`. This seems to have fixed the issue I was having. Hopefully this offers a solution for others using the **Slippry** script that might encounter this issue in the future.

**NOTE:** I just receive a email from one of the developers, and this 'bug' has been reported.